# Getting nids using entityfieldquery

Tags: drupal-7

I want to get all the nids but I am unable to get them. Below is my snippet.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
$query->entityCondition('bundle', 'product');
$query->propertyCondition('status', 1);
$query->fieldCondition('field_product_sub_cat', 'tid',array($leaf_nodes));
$query->range(0, 10);
$result = $query->execute();
if (isset($result['node']))
{
  $product_childnid = array_keys($result['node']);
}
```

Below is my result:**UPDATED**

```
Array
(
[node] => Array
    (
        [78] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 78
                [vid] => 78
                [type] => product
            )

        [80] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 80
                [vid] => 80
                [type] => product
            )

        [82] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 82
                [vid] => 82
                [type] => product
            )

        [84] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 84
                [vid] => 84
                [type] => product
            )

        [86] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 86
                [vid] => 86
                [type] => product
            )

        [88] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 88
                [vid] => 88
                [type] => product
            )

        [90] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 90
                [vid] => 90
                [type] => product
            )

        [92] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 92
                [vid] => 92
                [type] => product
            )

        [94] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 94
                [vid] => 94
                [type] => product
            )

        [100] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 100
                [vid] => 100
                [type] => product
              )
          )
  )
```

then below code is providing me all the paths too,

```
$paths = array();
if (isset($result['node']))
{
 foreach($result['node'] as $key => $node) 
 {
 $paths[$node->nid] = drupal_get_path_alias("node/$node->nid");
 }
}
```

now the next problem is how can I represent these paths in my anchor tag?Because  they all are in an array.Below is my array structure of paths aliases:

```
Array
(
 [78] => equivalent-fireman-glove-details
 [80] => toughguard®-2
 [82] => toughguard®-3
 [84] => toughguard-®sizzler®
 [86] => tough-guard-®
 [88] => kevlar®-double-glove
 [90] => nomex®-industrial-coverall
 [92] => tough-guard®-clinker®-0
 [94] => lab-coats-sa-nlc
)
```

and below is an array structure data to link with above paths:

```
Array
(
 [0] => 71
 [1] => 73
 [2] => 81
 [3] => 83
 [4] => 85
 [5] => 87
 [6] => 89
 [7] => 91
 [8] => 93
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query->fieldCondition('field_product_sub_cat', 'tid',array($leaf_nodes),'IN');
```

So that the query in compare value with array.

Comment: Thanku @rahul, my applied condition is true because when I try to output the `$result` using `print_r($result)` then I am getting array structure of nodes depending upon the field condition. But when I try to get all the `nids` using array_keys() then only the latest one appears in the output but I want all the nids. Thats my problem

Comment: @nomeer Please provide the expected result and the result you obtain from `print_r($result)`

Comment: have you tried l() ?
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7